# The method in the type is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Tags: java, methods

```
package com.testo.project1;

public class mathe {
    static int zahl1;
    static int zahl2;
    static int erg;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        add(5,4);       

    }

    public static void add(){

        zahl1 = this.zahl1;
        zahl2 = this.zahl2;
        erg=zahl1+zahl2;
        System.out.println(erg);
    }




}
```

Why does this code not work?
There are 2 ints when I call the method.
Does the Method need an object??

Comment: You have declared the method to take zero arguments...

Answer (score 2):

This code, no offense, is completely wrong, so I'll suggest an alternative.

The point here is that I'm having the method accept the two ints and then return them to main where the sum is printed.

```
package com.testo.project1;

public class mathe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(add(5,4));       
     }
     public static int add(int i1, int i2){

        return i1+i2;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Ingo See edits. I'm jumping between different revisions due to being kind of conflicted between keeping it similar to the original vs a complete restructure. I should be settled now.

Comment: How can you return s.th. when you say the method returns void??

Comment: @MadScientisto Again, refer to my previous comment and refresh the page to see my newest (final) version. `main` doesn't return anything, and `int add(` now does after I fixed the inconsistency I brought in.

Answer (score 1):

You want your method to get two integers, However it doesn't get anything "add()". It should be "add(int a, int b)".

In addition the two numbers shouldn't be as a part of the class.

Comment: "In addition all those static things are redundant." The static methods (add and void) are not redundant at all. Do you mean to say the fields are redundant?

Comment: @hexafraction yes :) Thanks for your answer. I am updating now

Answer (score 0):

There aren't two parameters in the `add` method.  Define two `int` parameters for that method.  Plus, those `static` variables aren't needed; just declare `erg` to be local variable for the sum.